# Код HTML символа

Tags: html, символы

Никак не могу найти код такой стрелки ◄

Помогите пож-та. А то xsl не позволяет просто так вставлять символ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Легкий самопиар: http://ling06.narod.ru/poleznoe/symbols.html

Comment: О, спасибо. Что за самопиар?

Comment: На доменное имя посмотрите :)

Comment: аааа, точно)

Answer (score 0):

О, нашёл) - &#9668;